# How to match 2 set of array and put it into element (div) in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have array that parse from json_encode from PHP like this :

```
[["1104", "1105", "1106", "1107"],[1, 2, 8, 9]]
```

I´m trying to generate div relate to number of array set1 (["1104", "1105", "1106", "1107"])

and I want to put array set2 inside it as  .innerHTML

In HTML page I have 4 dives like this

```
<div id='1104'></div>
<div id='1105'></div>
<div id='1106'></div>
<div id='1107'></div>
```

What I have tried is :

```
var str=xmlHttp.responseText;
var res=JSON.parse(str);

   var r = res[0]

   for (i in r){

     var diva = res[1]
    for (z in diva ){

   document.getElementById(r[i]).innerHTML=diva[z];

   }
    }
```

I can not get them into the correct place. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are actually seeing? I suspect the looping logic you are using is causing your problem.

Comment: What I want to do is to put the array set #2 (1, 2, 8, 9)
into the div name order by the first array.

Hopeless for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it. You don't need nested loops, just one loop that gets corresponding elements from both arrays.

```
var set1 = res[0], set2 = res[1];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById(set1[i]);
    if (div) {
        div.innerHTML = set2[i];
    }
}
```

If there are 3 sets:

```
var set1 = res[0], set2 = res[1], set3 = res[2];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById(set1[i]);
    if (div) {
        div.innerHTML = set2[i] + set3[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: please wait I´ll check it.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have one more question. What to do if I will have one more array to set in the same div ? Let´s say set3. Or this can does only 2 array ?

I have tried many ways but it make the div set 2not working.

Comment: This same approach works with as many arrays as you want. But you have to decide how to combine the data from `set2` and `set3` when putting them into the DIV.

Comment: what I did I put the set3 after set 2 ;
And then put  document.getElementById("set3"+set1[i]);

But this make the set2 not work

Comment: You have to use `set3[i]`, or course. Putting it in quotes just uses that string.

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: Well, Actually I use string + id to be the name of the div.(Sorry I have not told you in the beginning.) So that´s why I got problem
What I did now


var set1 = res[0], set2 = res[1], set3 = res[3];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    var div =  document.getElementById("inbx_lnav_ny"+set1[i]);
    if (div) {
        div.innerHTML = set2[i]+"(nye)";   
  $("#inbx_plhd_msg"+set1[i]).html(set3[i]);
   $("#"+set1[i]).addClass("inbx_unread");
    }
}



This make the div nr#2 not work. I don´t know why.

Comment: It's hard to read unformatted code in comments, but I think it should work. Since you've already accepted the answer to this question, maybe you should ask a new question. Show the new HTML that goes with your code. And I suggest you be consistent: either use raw javascript or jquery, but don't mix them (it's less confusing).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var Ids = res[0];
var values = res[1];

for (var i=0, len = Ids.length; i<len; i++) {
    document.getElementById(Ids[i]).innerHTML = values[i];
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJR5H/)

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop overwrites the previous values.

just replace the inner loop with `document.getElementById(r[i]).innerHTML=res[1].join(',');`